# Android - React Naitve - Shadow opacity higher when the component is bigger

Tags: android, react-native, android-elevation

I'm having an issue in Android when adding `elevation` to a View.
As we can see, in the first example, the shadow casted by adding `elevation` is the same size for both rectangles. In the second example however, the shadow for the grey rectangle is bigger than the shadow for the blue rectangle.

[image]

The styling is exactly the same, however the only difference is the size of the rectangles.

(written in React Native)

Rectangle A:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
  <View style={{elevation: 5, width: 140, height: 90, backgroundColor: "#d9d9d9"}} />
  <View style={{elevation: 5, width: 140, height: 60, backgroundColor: "#00aeef"}} />        
</View>
```

Rectangle B:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
  <View style={{elevation: 5, width: 220, height: 90, backgroundColor: "#d9d9d9"}} />
  <View style={{elevation: 5, width: 60, height: 60, backgroundColor: "#00aeef"}} />        
</View>
```

Adding a shadow to a parent component is not a solution since the component are not the same height. In such a case shadow will be visible above the blue component, and it just doesn't look right.

Also increasing the value of `elevation` of the blue rectangle is not a solution, since increasing the value of `elevation` spreads the shadow, making it less visible.

Any ideas how I can make the shadows look alike when both the component have different sizes?

Comment: I know that is not an efficient way, but why don't you put an if condition in elevation and decrease it in case of bigger width?